# How can I add all of my array values together in PHP?

Tags: php

How can I add all of my array values together in PHP? Is there a function for this?

Comment: next time provide more input. your array may contain numbers, so are you adding them up to give you a sum ? or do you want to join them to become one long string. ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If your array consists of numbers, you can use [**array_sum**](http://de.php.net/array_sum) to calculate a total. Example from the manual:

```
$a = array(2, 4, 6, 8);
echo "sum(a) = " . array_sum($a) . "\n";
```

If your array consists of strings, you can use [**implode**](http://www.php.net/implode):

```
implode(",", $array);
```

it would turn an array like this:

```
strawberries
peaches
pears
apples
```

into a string like this:

```
strawberries,peaches,pears,apples
```

Answer (score 2):

if your array are all numbers and you want to add them up, use [array_sum()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php). If not, you can use [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Answer (score 1):

[array_sum](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) function should help. Here I presume your array comprises of integer or float values.

Answer (score 0):

Let the given array values may contain integer or may not be.
It would be better to have check and filter the values.

```
$array = array(-5, "  ", 2, NULL, 13, "", 7, "\n", 4, "\t",  -2, "\t",  -8);

// removes all NULL, FALSE and Empty Strings but leaves 0 (zero) values

$result = array_filter( $array, 'is_numeric' );
echo array_sum($result);
```

Comment: Clever but unnecessary. `array_sum()` will cast strings to numbers anyway, so there's no need for this. If an array element returns `false` for `is_numeric()` then it will give zero when converted, and thus won't have any impact on `array_sum`, so there's no point filtering it. In your code, `array_sum($array)` will give the same result as `array_sum($result)`, without having to do the filtering.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.. I just tried to cover up all the possible scenarios in an array.