# Adding values in an array

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can i add all of my array values together in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439129/how-can-i-add-all-of-my-array-values-together-in-php)

I would like to add the numbers up in the array $m[2] for a total number of players online.

Whats the simplest way to do that, so I have the variable $total?

```
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($c, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://www.bungie.net/stats/reach/online.aspx',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    ));
$r = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);

preg_match_all('|([\w\s]+)</a> </h4>\s*([0-9,]+) Players|s', $r, $m);
$teams = array_combine($m[1], $m[2]);
foreach ($m[2] as &$v) $v = str_replace(',','',$v);
echo '<pre>'.print_r($m[2],1).'</pre>';
```

Comment: echo array_sum($m[2])."<br>\n"; at the end will just do the job for you.

Comment: @anubhava: Why `<br>`? Surely you mean to enclose the sum inside a `<p />` or a `<div />`? Or at least close the `<br>`...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[array_sum()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) ?