# How to sum array using function in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, function, foreach

I got exercise to do.
Need to create a function called `sumArray()` that should take an array as argument and return the sum of all items in the array. Answer with a call to the function using the array: `[4,256,5,13,1]`.Write your code below and put the answer into the variable ANSWER.

So long I came but it doesn't work.

```
function sumArray($array) {
    $total = 0;
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        $total += $value;
    }
    return $array;
}




$ANSWER = sumArray(4, 256, 5, 13, 1);
```

Comment: `return $total`

Comment: `4, 256, 5, 13, 1` this is not an array, you are using `foreach` inside the function

Comment: The call should be `sumArray([4, 256, 5, 13, 1])` to make the argument an array.

Comment: If you want to add an array up try [`array_sum()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php)

Comment: @NigelRen I knew someone was going to say that. Did you notice that it's an *exercise*? He's learning how to loop through arrays.

Comment: @Barmar, the question doesn't mention anything about having to loop through arrays, all it says that the function must return the sum of the array.

Comment: The first line says it's an exercise? What else could it be to learn?

Comment: @Barmar, it could be how to learn the methods that PHP provides for summing up arrays, but as I don't know what it may be - I don't make any assumptions at all.

Comment: 1 liner `echo eval('return '.implode('+', [4, 256, 5, 13, 1]).';');` ;p

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone you are right, but if i am beginner , and i dont know how to use array etc, than how can i use eval method?

Comment: SO is not a tutorial or homework completion site, if you don't know what an array is or how to use it or the numarous functions which operate on arrays, ask your tutor (they are paid) or [read the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) (its free).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add all of my array values together in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439129/how-can-i-add-all-of-my-array-values-together-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**So close.** Just 2 things to do.

```
function sumArray($array) {
    $total = 0;
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        $total += $value;
    }
//YOU NEED TO RETURN $total !! not $array
    return $total;
}
//the params given to sumArray() are not an array. just encapsule that in [] like: 
$ANSWER = sumArray([4, 256, 5, 13, 1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use PHP's built in array_sum method.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php

```
$ANSWER = array_sum(array(4, 256, 5, 13, 1));
```

If you must create a function then wrap it.

```
function sumArray($array) {
    return array_sum($array);
}
$ANSWER = sumArray(array(4, 256, 5, 13, 1));
```

Note. In your example you haven't provided an array you have various arguments. You could also do that like so:

```
function sumArray() {
    return array_sum(func_get_args());
}
$ANSWER = sumArray(4, 256, 5, 13, 1);
```

Edit. As this answer got down voted for not providing an example on how to add it up here it is. Though you should always use the built in function if it's a available and teaching you to avoid it is counterintuitive.

```
function sumArray($array) {
    for($i = 0, $total = 0; $i < count($array); $total+=$array[$i++]);
    return $total;
}

$ANSWER = sumArray([4, 256, 5, 13, 1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to return `$total`, you are again returning your array.

Second, you must need to pass array in function argument as:

```
$sumArray = array(4, 256, 5, 13, 1); // your array
$myAnswer = sumArray($sumArray); // calling function
```

**Example:**

```
<?php 
function sumArray($array) {
    $total = 0;
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        $total += $value;
    }
    return $total;
}

/** Your array **/
$sumArray = array(4, 256, 5, 13, 1);

/** Calling function **/
$myAnswer = sumArray($sumArray);

/** Your result **/
echo $myAnswer; //279 result
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you need to write a function, your code should look like this:

```
function sumArray($array) {
    $total = 0;
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        $total += $value;
    }
    return $total;
}




$ANSWER = sumArray(array(4, 256, 5, 13, 1));
```

Your code isn't working because you're not passing an array to the function, and you're also returning the parameter and not the $total variable.

Alternatively, you can use array_sum inside a function of your own.

Comment: It's an academic exercise.

Comment: @Barmar: There is no mention in the question about any constraints the code has to fulfill, other than (quote): "to create a function called `sumArray()` that should take an array as argument and return the sum of all items in the array." No constraints are placed on how to write that function.

Comment: @Roy: There is no mention in the question about any constraints the code has to fulfill, other than (quote): "to create a function called `sumArray()` that should take an array as argument and return the sum of all items in the array." No constraints are placed on how to write that function.